# Probability of dice roll between values

Tags: probability, dice

Context: In calculating the optimal policy for [MDP's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) an algorithm called Value Iteration is used. I am using this algorithm to calculate the optimal policy for a small game and test my knowledge in the field.

In the game, $d$ normal dices (1-6) are rolled simultaneously, and you can either pick all dices with the largest value, or all dices with the smallest value. To not have to compute all possible $6^d$ dice rolls, I limit it to $x$ dices getting the smallest values, and $y$ dices getting the highest values, where $1 \leq x \leq d$ and $y \leq d - x$.

Now my question is: With $d$ dices, what is the probability that $x$ dices fall on a minimum value $v_x$, $y$ dices fall on a maximum value $v_y > v_x$, and $z = d - (x+y)$ dices are between (not including) $(v_x, v_y)$?

I have the feeling that the $z$ in-between dices can be modeled with a binomial distribution with $binom(z, d, \frac{v_y - v_x - 1}{6})$, but I am not sure how to reconcile this with the probabilities of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: would this not depend on what $v_x,v_y$ are? so effectively there are 36 cases? for example, if $v_x =1$, and $v_y=6$, then the probability is $\binom{d}{x}\binom{d-x}{y}/\binom{d+6-1}{6-1}$, for each case the calculation would be separate i guess?

Comment: How would you encode the event with all dice showing up the same value?

Comment: then $x = d$, $y = 0$ and $z = 0$. The value for $v_y$ would be undefined. Perhaps this case should be handled separately, if it would not fit into a possible formula.

Comment: What is the **purpose** of this exercise. ? Does it have some practical use or is it just some problem you have conjured up ?

Comment: It is an exercise I set myself to derive the optimal policy in every state of the Dutch game dertigen (Dutch link, could not find an English translation: https://drankspellen.fandom.com/nl/wiki/Dertigen ). 
The game exists, but I use it as a toy example to test my knowledge in MDP's, specifically in Value Iteration and Policy Iteration as the game has a different stochastic nature than what is common in MDP's. The outcome after an action is nonrandom, but after the outcome state of doing an action, a probability exists of going to some other state: The roll of a dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $v_x<v_y$, $0<x,0<y,x+y\le d$ the probability reads:
$$
p(x,y,v_x,v_y)=\frac{d!}{x!y!(d-x-y)!}\frac{(v_y-v_x-1)^{d-x-y}}{6^d},\tag1
$$
with the convention $0^0=1$. The probabilities do not sum to $1$ because the allowed events do not include the cases with $v_x=v_y$, i.e. the events with all dice showing up the same value, the probability of such events being $\frac1{6^{d-1}}$. One can notice that the formula $(1)$ is applicable in the case $v_x=v_y$ as well provided the convention that one of $x,y$ is $d$ and the other is $0$.